# Shadows Render Directly to Buffer?

Tags: opengl

Say i only have one light source, the sun, and i only want shadows to appear on certain static geometry from other independent object. The buffers are filled already with only the static geometry (depth and color). So rather than rendering the shadows onto a texture and then that texture is used on the static geometry (i believe this is how shadow mapping works). Is there a way i can draw shadows, without using a texture as a medium and instead using a depth test to then multiply the shadow onto the color buffer?

Comment: Something like [stencil shadows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_volume)?

Comment: Yes i believe that is what i am looking for, at a glance.